# How can I control the accuracy of the input parameters into the shgo-algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, shgo

I realized that during the optimization using shgo-algorithm, especially in the local optimization, the algorithm choses very small (e-10) steps by changing the input parameter. Ist there a command to change this to 0.1? As my range is between 50 and 100, this ist sufficiently accurate.

The documentatio leaves me a bit clueless.